# Formal argument cannot be constant def

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

As the title suggests, I am getting that error when I go to run my program.

Here is my ruby file:

```
require 'java'
java_import org.arc.Something

def hello(Something)
    Something.print()
end
```

And basically I'm calling it like this:

```
invoke.invokeFunction("hello", new SomethingElse());
```

Answer (score 3):

As it said in the error message, you can't use constant as formal argument in ruby.

Constants have the names like local variables, except that they begin with a capital letter.

So, you should just use usual variable in place of argument:

```
def hello(something)
    something.print()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a conflict between one of your constants name (`[arc.org.]Something`) and the parameter name (`Something`).

Try renaming your parameter to something else:

```
require 'java'
java_import org.arc.Something

def hello(st)
    st.print()
end
```